# add fields directly to node table?

Tags: entities

Is it a good idea to add field directly to the node table via db_add_field and schema_alter? e.g. i want to add just number of views field to it. I know the recommended approach is field api but find it kind of overkill to create a new table just for a simple field like that. Let me know your views on that approach.. has anyone done it in a project?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is not drupal standard, sometimes is needed to do things like that.

I prefer to [create my own entities](http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/creating-own-entities-entity-api) that to modify the node entity. This way if you use entity api as base this is integrated with views out of the box. Another approach to that not require coding is [ECK module](https://drupal.org/project/eck), you can define properties to the entity and this will be added on the same entity table as and extra column.

Comment: ECK + properties would be the same as me adding fields directly to the no table and using schema_alter right? My original plan was to create my own entity for something completely clean but there are so much modules not 100% compatible with custom entities and designed for node only... most obvious one is drupal's own comments which are associated to nodes only.. and there are seo and search modules mostly for nodes... custom entity support is sometimes lacking making you having to reinvent the wheel to adapt to entities

Comment: As you said there is so many modules node oriented, if you want to use them I'll choose your first option (drupal alter_schema or a custom table to join, fields tables are perfect to save revision's data but it is not always is needed).